# Detecting an object colliding with itself - snake or rope example

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collider

I have a custom mesh I've created for a game object. I want to do some actions when it touches itself. I tried attaching the collider and the script to the mesh. However the script is called only when colliding with other objects. How can I detect colliding with itself?

Comment: You don't use MeshColliders in games.  Ever.  (Only in extremely unusual cases, specifically about the only real uses is for the surfaces of tracks (in say a car racing game).)  This is a huge point of confusion in Unity, for new and hobbyist developers.  The fact that the documentation and some web pages mention "mesh colliders" once or twice has led to phenomenal confusion.  So, you don't use those.

Comment: What else can I use? @JoeBlow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a game physics engine, such as PhysX: there is no meaningful sense in which a collider can collide with itself.

Note that, in games and 3D engineering, "things" almost always have ***more than one* collider**.

For example, a doggie might be made of, oh, seven or so colliders (you can imagine one for the torso (perhaps a sphere there), four legs (probably capsule or just rectangle), one for the head (spehere again), and if relevant in the game one for the tail (probably just a rectangle - or maybe two small spheres).  For a car, you might have say three boxes for the overall shape of the body, and you likely have individual colliders for "where you need to know what hit" ... eg, the bumpers, maybe the doors if you expect it to be bashed there, and so on.

Now,

regarding your question, it looks like you have -- for example -- a humanoid, which would have a number of colliders as described in the previous paragraph.

It could be that, for example, **the arm collider can hit the leg collider**, and you want to know that.

It is impossible to help you with your question, unless, you explain what your scene is in general terms...

--

If you're making **a snake or perhaps rope**, do what Gunnar said. The simplest solution is a number of sphere colliders.

Quite simply say your snake is 10 centimeters thick.  Say your snake is 2 meters long.  Quite simply have sphere colliders about 9-10 cm in size.  Separate them so they are not touching one another but a bit spaced.  So for 2m you might have about 15 of them.  That's all there is to it.

Please note that engineering ropes / snakes is far from easy.

I encourage you to glance at the **AssetStore** and look at the may excellent rope/snake packages available.

Realise that it can take ***man-years*** of engineering to develop a perfect rope system.

Understand that an everyday aspect of Unity (or game engineering in general), is that you have to use an existing, often well-known solution, for the problem  at hand.  Good luck.

Comment: My guess would be something like snake where you can run into yourself. As mentioned: Having multiple colliders and asking for the tag of the gameobject will most likely be the solution.

Comment: yes, actually @GunnarB. is right and that's exactly what i meant

Comment: Yes it's 3D, thank you it helped me a lot in figuring out what to do to build this model